# Updating data with information received from the view (Grails)

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, view, controller

I am writing a Grails app and I have a quick question about the best way to do something. My controller has 2 lists of data, both of which are displayed on the view in separate HTML tables. What I want to do is to have a button that will allow you to move an item from one list to the other. What is the best way to do this?

I have done some research and using some form of AJAX seems to be the general consensus on the best way to do this. Is there any other way? The heart of the problem is that I can't figure out how to update the data contained in the contoller based on the button the user presses in the view.

Thanks

Comment: You can update the data when user submits the whole page with both tables. Do you have a clear understanding what Ajax action submits and what should a whole page submission send to server?

Comment: No, not really. I've never used AJAX before. What should I be reading up on to submit both these tables using AJAX?

Comment: @Sum: you should learn about javascript first, then look for the concept of Ajax. But I want to propose a way that don't use ajax: you can use javascript to move the items in the client side, and have a submit button for user to submit the result after editing.

Comment: For example, you have 2 list at client side, and two "go left" and "go right button". "Go left" make the selected item in left list disappear and insert that item in right list. The same for the "go right". Then after user editing, you just need to submit both list. It require some playing with HTML elements (DOM element), but I think you can handle it.

Comment: Well, I'd start with understanding how HTML form submission works (i.e. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and what Ajax does about it (http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.7%20Ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just updating the model to reflect the new lists and rerendering the page